# Oracle applications logs user in after entering password incorrectly 50 times

Tags: oracle, security, authentication

We have an issue with our Oracle Applications 12.2.4 environment, whereby a user is logged into the application after entering an incorrect password 50 times. Basically you enter any username and then an invalid password. Click Login 50 times. It pops up a notification saying you have reached the maximum number of login attempts, and then when you click OK it does not log you out but instead logs you in.

Needless to say this is a high priority issue, since employees' sensitive data (salaries, performance ratings, medical information, bonuses, performance reviews, share allocations, incentives, grievances, sexual harassment trials, etc.) are exposed by this security bug. So far we have had no response to our P1 service request with Oracle Support.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Is there a patch to fix this? Is there a profile option that controls this/or fixes this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has provided patch 26663218, which fixed the issue.